# Multiplication of RDD row to all other rows in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, vector, pyspark, rdd, matrix-multiplication

I have an RDD of DenseVector objects and I want to:

1. Select one of these vectors (one row)
2. Perform a multiplication of this vector to all other vector rows in order to compute a similarity (cosine)

Basically I am trying to perform a dot product between a vector and a matrix, starting from an RDD. For reference, the RDD contains TF-IDF values built with Spark ML, which furnishes a dataframe of SparseVectors, and have been mapped to DenseVectors in order to do the multiplication. The dataframe and corresponding RDD are called `tfidf_df` and `tfidf_rdd` respectively.

What I do, which works is (full script with sample data)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.ml.feature import IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

import numpy as np

sc = SparkContext()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
spark_session = SparkSession(sc)

sentenceData = spark_session.createDataFrame([
         (0, "I go to school school is good"),
         (1, "I like school"),
         (2, "I also like cinema")
], ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="tokens")
tokens_df = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

# TF feats
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="tokens", 
                                   outputCol="tf_features")
model = count_vectorizer.fit(tokens_df)
tf_df = model.transform(tokens_df)

print(model.vocabulary)
print(tf_df.rdd.take(5))

idf = IDF(inputCol="tf_features",
          outputCol="tf_idf_features",
      )
model = idf.fit(tf_df)
tfidf_df = model.transform(tf_df)

# Transform into RDD of dense vectors
tfidf_rdd = tfidf_df.select("tf_idf_features") \
     .rdd \
     .map(lambda row: DenseVector(row.tf_idf_features.toArray()))

print(tfidf_rdd.take(3))

# Select the test vector
test_label = 1

vec = tfidf_df.filter(tfidf_df.label == test_label) \
    .select('tf_idf_features') \
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda row: DenseVector(row.tf_idf_features.toArray())).collect()[0]

rddB = tfidf_rdd.map(lambda row: np.dot(row/np.linalg.norm(row),
                                        vec/np.linalg.norm(vec))) \
                .zipWithIndex()

# print('*** multiplication', rddB.take(20))


# Sort the similarities
sorted_rddB = rddB.sortByKey(False)

print(sorted_rddB.take(20))
```

The test vector has been selected as the one whose label is 1. The end result with similarities is (from the last print statement) `[(1.0000000000000002, 1), (0.27105728525552131, 0), (0.1991208898963957, 2)]` where indexing has been used to trace back to the original dataset.

This works fine but looks a bit clunky. I'd be looking for the best practices to perform a multiplication between a selected row of a dataframe (vector) with all the dataframe vectors. Am open to any suggestions over the workflow, specifically performance - related.

Comment: Clear question. However, it would help if you could add a reproducible example; some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Florian Good idea, I've added full script and results.